# Translating "Done" button on iOS keyboard to other language

Tags: ios, cordova, translation

Using Cordova/Phonegap, what is the easiest way to translate the "Done" button present on the iOS virtual keyboard?

For instance, my iPhone is configured as using French language.
However, the button still shows "Done" button and not the classic French adapted word: "Ok".

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same problem with my cordova app. I fixed it with a plugin that writes in the Info.plist

```
<plugin id="com.example.plugin" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <name>Example</name>
    <description>A label translate example</description>    
    <platform name="ios">
        <config-file target="*-Info.plist">
            <key>CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations</key>
            <array>
                <string>Yes</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
            <array>
                <string>fr</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
            <array>
                <string>fr_FR</string>
            </array>
        </config-file>  
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

Comment: For some reason I needed to set the key using `parent=` in `config-file`, but then it worked. [Example is here](https://github.com/escapedcat/cordova-plugin-localization-ios)

Comment: its not working for me in iphone 7..Do you have any idea?

Comment: but where do you put the put the actual strings then?

Answer (score 3):

Setting this property in **Info** tab was enough:

[image]

Comment: i dont have my region in this list, what to do?

Comment: with this change, keyboard will always show single language..it wont work with i18n.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations` .plist key is also possible via your `config.xml`. Just add this in your iOS platform configuration:

```
<platform name="ios">
  <config-file parent="CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
    <true />
  </config-file>
</platform>
```

Comment: It's working on my projet. The "Done" button is translate to "OK" in French. Have you check that your Info.plist file has changed in Xcode ? Have your check iOS device language ? It is the device OS that decide of the language to display.

Comment: Nope it did not wokred.

Comment: I had to explicitly add  property 'Localized resources can be mixed' : YES, from Xcode Info tab, then it worked for all languages.

Comment: Tested and re-tested this morning: it's working.
My config : 
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 
Cordova Platforms  :  ios 4.5.4
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1

You did something wrong with your project. Delete your iOS platform and re-add it.