# Cordova 6.0.0 iOS localization with cordova-ios@4.0 and Xcode 7.2.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

The default language of my cordova-ios@4.0 project is set to English in Apple Xcode using Cordova 6.0.0 CLI. The iOS context menus will use English even though the iOS device language is localized, such as the select/select all/copy/paste -menu. How can I localize the Cordova app to Norwegian (nb) in Xcode, please?

Comment: To do it in more Cordova's style, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46405401/2728710

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change this on the info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>nb</string>
```

Or add this:

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>nb</string>
</array>
```