# Ionic - hide iOS selection wheel (select options) after selection

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to hide Ionic (iOS) "selection wheel" which is displayed after user want to select one of the select tag options.

I know that can be achieved by showing keyboard accessory bar and "done" button but that button text is hardcoded (and as far as I know we cannot translate it to other languages). So this is not an option.

I am also not available to use "change" event for the select, because its not triggered until selection wheel is being hidden.

Is there any way to:

1. Change "done" button text in accessory bar?
2. Detect changed value in selection wheel on iOS and hide it

programatically?

Thank you

Comment: Did you tried to use a Custom BarButtonItem and place your text there?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196249/cordova-6-0-0-ios-localization-with-cordova-ios4-0-and-xcode-7-2-1 ?

Comment: Let me know if you don't know how, to show you how to make a custom `BarButtonItem` instead of use system buttons.

Comment: @daserge the "done" button will get translated according to the device language, is this not enough?

Comment: No, the button is not translated unless the device language is supported by the project as explained on daserge's link

Comment: @dease Did you had a look at that plugin i mentioned?

Answer (score 3):

To "translate" the "Done" button you can follow the approach on
[Cordova 6.0.0 iOS localization with cordova-ios@4.0 and Xcode 7.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196249/cordova-6-0-0-ios-localization-with-cordova-ios4-0-and-xcode-7-2-1)

Change the CFBundleDevelopmentRegion

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>es</string>
```

Or add the localizations you want to support (will work if the device has set any of that localizations)

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>es</string>
    <string>en</string>
    <string>fr</string>
</array>
```

To make this changes you should use a "dumb" plugin that just writes on the info.plist using the `config-file` [tag](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#config-file), or use a [hook](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html)

You can also use a native component to show the list of options instead of using the select tag

There are probably a few plugins available, you can try [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-listpicker), it doesn't have a method to hide the wheel, but it could be implemented, try opening an issue on the plugin github repo.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [cordova plugin picker](https://github.com/mzbyszynski/cordova-plugin-picker) should help you out in this case.

This plugin allows for more dynamic access to the picker widget normally displayed when a `<select>` is tapped, in particular on ios. This plugin allows direct control of the PickerView and what options are shown. This enables lazy-loading display options, dynamically changing options and paging large data sets.

Since it gives more control of the picker view, it should help you out. Please check.